# Separate wrapper with api request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React. Tell me how to make it beautifully (right!). On the page, I have two almost identical sections:

[image]

And I'm trying to follow the rule, keep containers and components separate. There is a wrapper in which there is one api request to receive a picture (hereinafter it is transmitted as a props) for a specific section, it is rendered in this way:

[image]

It turns out that this wrapper is (almost) the same:

[image]

I understand that this can be done correctly, but something does not work. I am confused by the fact that it is necessary to return two different components from the wrapper, where the api request to receive a picture goes. (I was looking towards hoc, but I haven't figured out how to use it myself). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it all the same through hoc. Here is the component itself:

```
function LoadingSnapshotHOC(Component) {
  const NewComponent = (props) => {
    const isMounted = useIsMounted();
    const state = useSelector(({ dateParams }) => {
      const { currentPage } = props;
      return {
        selectedTimeLabel: dateParams?.[currentPage].selectedTimePeriod.label,
        compareTimeLabel: dateParams?.[currentPage].compareTimePeriod.label,
      };
    });

    const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState("");

    const updateSnapshot = async (deviceID) => {
      const img = await getSnapshot(deviceID);
      img.onload = () => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setSnapshot(img);
        }
      };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.deviceID) updateSnapshot(props.deviceID);
    }, [props.deviceID]);

    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        snapshot={snapshot}
        selectedTimeLabel={state.selectedTimeLabel}
        compareTimeLabel={state.compareTimeLabel}
      />
    );
  };
  return NewComponent;
}
export default LoadingSnapshotHOC;
```

Next, I wrapped my components:

```
function HeatMapSnapshot({...}) {
...
}
export default LoadingSnapshotHOC(HeatMapSnapshot);
```

and

```
function TrafficFlowSnapshot({...}) {
...
}
export default LoadingSnapshotHOC(TrafficFlowSnapshot);
```

And their render. Thank you all for your attention!
[image]